# Dropdown menu content CSS padding

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Hey i have my drop down menu here:
https://i.gyazo.com/642cdb023365cd8e7e086d53551fc385.png

I am having trouble getting the drop down text closer together i tried putting padding on `content a {}` but it doesn't seem to work

I included the html mark up as well along with the other styles I used for my nav bar.

```css
nav {
    padding-left: 5px
}

nav .main-nav {
 height: 80px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 64px;
    background: url(../images/navHeader.png) no-repeat top;
    position: relative
}

nav .main-nav ul {
    width: 360px;
    height: 80px;
 margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none
}

nav .main-nav ul a,
nav .main-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 115px;
    line-height: 80px;
    height: 80px
  
}

nav .main-nav ul a {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 750;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #84827d;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out
}

nav .main-nav ul a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7289da
}
nav .main-nav li .dropdown {
    }
    nav .main-nav .dropdown-content {
        position: absolute;
     display: none;
     float: left;
     z-index: 10;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 background: #3A4FC5;
 color: #656161;
 opacity: .8;
 min-width: 10%;
 top: 60px;
    }

    nav .main-nav .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    }
    nav .main-nav .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #3A4FC5
    }

    nav .main-nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="main-nav">
    <ul class="left">
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Home</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Third</a>
          <a href="#">Third Link</a>
          <a href="#">Third Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Gods</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Goddesses</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="play-now"></div>
    <ul class="right">
      <li><a href="#">Heroes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Myths</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Beasts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the HTML mark up for your problem also.

Comment: Added it to the main topic.

Comment: put this in a codepen or something this way it's easier for people to help you since they don't have to copy and paste the code elsewhere.

Comment: Based on the code that you've given dropdown menu items have no space between. You need to provide more of the original code for someone to identify the problem.

Comment: Added more of what you may need to assist me with my issues.

Answer (score 0):

This was problem with your code:

```
nav.main-nav ul a,
nav.main-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 115px;
    line-height: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

You set `line-height` and `height` to be fixed size. 
If you remove `height`and set, for example, `line-height: 2em;` it should be much better.

```
nav.main-nav ul a, 
nav.main-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 115px;
    line-height: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `height` and `line-height` in tis rule:

```
nav .main-nav ul a,
nav .main-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 115px;
  line-height: 8px;
  height: 80px
}
```

That will solve your problem - I changed it to 30 px in the snippet below:

```css
nav {
  padding-left: 5px
}

nav .main-nav {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 64px;
  background: url(../images/navHeader.png) no-repeat top;
  position: relative
}

nav .main-nav ul {
  width: 360px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none
}

nav .main-nav ul a,
nav .main-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 115px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px
}

nav .main-nav ul a {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 750;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #84827d;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out
}

nav .main-nav ul a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #7289da
}

nav .main-nav li .dropdown {}

nav .main-nav .dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: #3A4FC5;
  color: #656161;
  opacity: .8;
  min-width: 10%;
  top: 60px;
}

nav .main-nav .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

nav .main-nav .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #3A4FC5
}

nav .main-nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="main-nav">
    <ul class="left">
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Home</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Third</a>
          <a href="#">Third Link</a>
          <a href="#">Third Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Gods</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Goddesses</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="play-now"></div>
    <ul class="right">
      <li><a href="#">Heroes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Myths</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Beasts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown anchors inherit properties from the following rule:

```
nav .main-nav ul a,
nav .main-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 115px;
    line-height: 80px;
    height: 80px

}
```

You can provide a more specific rule below like this:

```
nav .main-nav .dropdown-content a {
/* Set your height and line-height to whatever you want it to be to make the space between your items smaller */
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px
}
```

An easier way to manage this however would be set the height and line-height to their initial values and use padding:

```
nav .main-nav .dropdown-content a {
  height: auto;
  line-height: initial;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```